# Curl output not displayed for gremlin query

Tags: curl, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

Trying to execute a query using curl. The output is not displayed on the terminal.
Reference used: https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/server/

Command used on server:

```
curl -v -POST -H 'Content-type: application/json'  http://localhost:8182 -d '{"gremlin": "g.V().count()"}'
```

Output:

```
 * Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8182/
 *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
 * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8182 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8182
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 57
>
 * upload completely sent off: 57 out of 57 bytes
```

It gets stuck here, hence I terminate it.
I want the count displayed on the screen or in a specified file.

Comment: Is Janus Server configured for HTTP requests? https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/server/#janusgraph-server-as-a-http-endpoint if it is configured for just websockets that could be the problem...

Comment: yes it is configured for both Web Socket and Http

Answer (score 1):

`curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8182'  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'  --data-raw '{"gremlin":"g.V().count()"}'`

Works for me.
I think you can check janusgraph's log. See if janusgraph server recived  your request.